# MySQL: Get data from multiple tables allowing nulls with a list of ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, mysql-workbench

I got this tables that look like this:

**table 1**

```
|id|value1|value2|value3
```

**table 2**

```
|id|value4|value5|value6
```

The id value in each table is unique but an id could appear in a table 1 but no in table 2. (value 1 is equal to value4 but if id dont appear in table 2 value4 would be null... )

Then I got this a of ids and I want to get sometime like (supossing that id appear in table 1 but no in 2 and vice versa):

**resultgrid**
`|  id  | value1| value2| value3|value4|value5|value6`

```
|838383|result1|result2|result3|null  |null  |null
|548438|null   |null   |null   |result4|result5|result6
```

hope you guys can help me, thanks!

EDIT: query i've been trying (it's actually a set of collected pieces of answer i'd see in stack overflow)

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.value4, t2.value5, t2.value6
FROM table1 as t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
Where t1.id = t2.id = 838383
```

this get me 0 rows returned.

I want to make it general to use the <2000 id list.

Comment: Show your query, please. We cannot fix it if you won't share it with us. And also add what data you're currently getting.

Comment: What if there are matching id rows in both the table. Will they be shown or not ?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy sure, i did try mutiple querys, I edited with the last I did try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `full outer join` which MySQL does not support.  In your case, you can emulate this with `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.value4, t2.value5, t2.value6
from (select 838383 as id
     ) i left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.id = i.id left join
     table2 t2 
     on t2.id = i.id;
```

The list of ids you want to keep goes in the `i` subquery.

Comment: This one help me to solve my problem but I ended up making a python script to movie through the list.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use two different `Select` queries, using `Left join` between the two tables. In the first query, consider `table1` as leftmost table; and `table2` as leftmost in the second query.
- Use `Where <right table id> IS NULL` to filter out rows where there is no matching entry in the rightmost table.
- Use [`Union`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine the resultset. Since there will not be any duplicates (due to our query results), we can use `Union All`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value1, t1.value2, t1.value3, 
              t2.value4, t2.value5, t2.value6 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL 

UNION ALL 

SELECT t2.id, t1.value1, t1.value2, t1.value3, 
              t2.value4, t2.value5, t2.value6 
FROM table2 AS t2 
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

Comment: i doubt that this will give the topicstarters correct result he is after.. it looks like he looking for a pivot query to convert cross table records into columns. 9 out of the 10 times this is done with `MAX(CASE END)` in combination with `GROUP BY` besides it looks like this query needs to be used as a subquery to get the pivotting going.  But hard to say for sure without example data..

Comment: @RaymondNijland sample data is not enough. Based on limited understanding of OP's words, and given dataset - current query seems to fulfill that requirement

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya This give me a resultgrid like the example i did post  but missing the part for generalize it for a list of id, I know it's not possible (as far my understanding of Mysql) but i could make it with a list of 10 ids.

Comment: @S.Teves you can use where condition. Can you edit your question to add the specific case u need.

Comment: @S.Teves add `and t1.id < 2000` in the first select query and `and t2.id < 2000` in the second select query (as I understand that you need to get results for all id < 2000)